# C# How can I Validate a User input before it is placed into my array?

Tags: c#, arrays, validation, histogram

I am very new to C# and I was wondering how I can validate user input before placing their input in my array. I am trying to create a console application to create a vertical and horizontal histogram, made of stars. So I am asking the user for 8 numbers between 1-10 and printing their results onto the screen as a histogram. 
I need help with 3 things:
1. How can I make it so that they can only enter numbers into the menu and the array? 
2. I'm not sure how to display the histogram vertically, I've done the horizontal one and can't figure out how to make it vertical. 
3. Also, I'd like to have labels going down the histograms. E.g

```
1 **** (Number of stars user selected) 
2 ****** (Number of stars user selected)
3 ***** (Number of stars user selected)
4 * etc.
```

Would greatly appreciate any help! Thank you so much in advance. :)
Here is what I've got so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise_3A
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            clsMainMenu MainMenu = new clsMainMenu();
            ConsoleKeyInfo ConsoleKeyPressed;

            do
            {
                MainMenu.DisplayMenu();
                ConsoleKeyPressed = Console.ReadKey(false);
                Console.WriteLine();
                switch (ConsoleKeyPressed.KeyChar.ToString())
                {
                    case "1":
                        clsHistogram Histogram = new clsHistogram();
                        Histogram.CreateHorizontalHistogram();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        clsHistogram HistogramV = new clsHistogram();
                        HistogramV.CreateVerticalHistogram();
                        break;
                }
            } while (ConsoleKeyPressed.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise_3A
{
    class clsMainMenu
    {
        public void DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1. Create a Horizontal Histogram.");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Create a Vertical Histogram.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Esc to exit the Program.");
            Console.WriteLine("..................................");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise_3A
{
    class clsHistogram
    {
        string strNumberChosen = "";

        public void CreateHorizontalHistogram()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 10:");

            int[] intHistogramArray = new int[8];

            for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 8; intCounter++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number " + (intCounter + 1) + " :");
                strNumberChosen = Console.ReadLine(); // Need Data Validation Here.             
            } // Populating Array.

            Console.WriteLine("Your Histogram looks like this: ");
            for (int intcounter = 0; intcounter < 8; intcounter++)
            {
                int intStarPlot = intHistogramArray[intcounter];
                while (intStarPlot > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(" *");
                    intStarPlot -= 1;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            } // Display a Horizontal Array.
        }


        public void CreateVerticalHistogram()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 10:");

            int[] intHistogramArray = new int[8];

            for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 8; intCounter++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number " + (intCounter + 1) + " :");
                strNumberChosen = Console.ReadLine(); // Need Data Validation Here.
            } // Populating Array.

            Console.WriteLine("Your Histogram looks like this: ");
            for (int intcounter = 0; intcounter < 8; intcounter++)
            {
                int intStarPlot = intHistogramArray[intcounter];
                while (intStarPlot > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(" * \n");
                    intStarPlot -= 1;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            } // Display a Vertical Array.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not pack three questions into one single SO question. Each should be dealt with individually for clarity.

Comment: As far as the first point is concerned I would suggest you take one of these two possible approaches: `bool isNumber = Int32.TryParse(strNumberChosen, out var num);` which can be evaluated or use Regular Expressions to evaluate the input: `var reg = new Regex(@"[0-9]");  bool isNumber = reg.IsMatch(strNumberChosen);`

Comment: Hi Barns, Sorry I didn't know about not putting multiple questions. Thank you for your answer, I think your first solution would be best for me. However, I don't quite understand it, where in my code would I place that line? And also do I need to do anything else in order for it to work? Such as if the user enters a letter, allow them to try again until they enter a number.
Many thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of code that would use the `int.TryParse()` method to evaluate the entered data.

```
    private static readonly char star = '*';
    private static readonly uint minValue = 1;
    private static readonly int maxValue = 10;

    private static void CreateHorizontalHistogram()
    {
        var limits = "a number between " + minValue + " and " + maxValue + ": ";
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter " + limits);

        var list = new List<int>();

        do
        {
            var message = string.Empty;
            bool isNumber = false;
            bool isRightSize = false;
            int output;

            do
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();      
                isNumber = int.TryParse(input, out output);
                if(isNumber)
                {
                    isRightSize = minValue <= output && output <= maxValue;
                    message = isRightSize ? "That will do: " : "Try again - value is not " + limits + output;
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Try again - " + input + " is not a Number";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }while(!isNumber || !isRightSize);

            Console.WriteLine("Entered number at position" + (list.Count + 1) + " : " + output);
            list.Add(output);
        }while(list.Count <= 8);

        Console.WriteLine("Your Histogram looks like this: ");
        foreach(var value in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty.PadRight(value, star));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Or like this with LINQ");
        list.ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(string.Empty.PadRight(n, star)));
    }
```

---

**NOTE:** 
I used a `List<int>` of integers instead of an array `int[]`...my personal preference.
I changed the way the diagram was created. My version is a bit less verbose.
I also added an additional example of how you could create the diagram using `LINQ`-- always looks good.

Please, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much, Barns. You're a genius. It works perfectly! I put it into my code and it's amazing thank you so much for your help. Now I need to figure out how to display that vertically lol. Thank you so much again, I really appreciate you.